# How do I change the style source to point locally?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below are three lines, two of which point to some scripts which makes a dialog box open etc. But the top one is a link which points towards the styling. It uses the web, I know the location on my machine. I'm just not sure how to point to it locally.

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Microsoft tutorial</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming here that you already copied the `jquery-ui.css` file to its local folder, if not do it. Then just update the `link` element as follow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/jquery-ui.css"  />
```

Where `/path/to` is the actual path to your css file. Something like `~/Styles` or `~/Styles/jquery-ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness`.